# Child process can't access shared memory in C

Tags: c, shared-memory

I have a program where I want to set up a pointer to a struct as shared memory. I think I've set up the shared memory correctly in the main method; then I call a function to initialize the struct, and fork. However, the child process can't access the shared memory; the parent process works as expected, which isn't that big of a surprise. I know for sure that the child process executes and works, but it cannot access the shared memory, so the function doesn't really do much besides print out printf statements.

```
struct OverSharedData{
    struct SharedData ** rep;
    int rop;
};

void initialize( struct OverSharedData * bill){
bill->rep = (struct SharedData**)malloc(sizeof(struct SharedData*)*consumerthreads);
int on =0;
for (on=0; on<consumerthreads; on++) {
    *(bill->rep+on) = (struct SharedData *)malloc(sizeof(struct SharedData));
    init(*(bill->rep + on), on); //
 }}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    databases(argv[1]); /* Takes care of setting up the database*/
    categories(argv[2]); /*Takes care of setting up the book categories*/
    bookorders = argv[3];

    key_t key = ftok("garbage.txt", 71);
    int eyedee = shmget(key, sizeof(struct OverSharedData ),
                        IPC_CREAT | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP);
    if (eyedee == -1)
    {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct OverSharedData *remp = (struct OverSharedData *) shmat(eyedee, 0, 0);

    if (remp == (void *) -1)
    {
        perror("shmat");
        exit(1);
    }

    initialize(remp);
    struct SharedData * d = *(remp->rep + 0);


    printf("Hallo\n");
    shmctl(eyedee, IPC_RMID, 0);



    pid_t forkk = fork();

    if (forkk==0) {
        /*THIS DOES NOT WORK*/
        printf("Entered consumer check: %d\n", remp->rop);

         int z = 0;
         pthread_t Consumer_Threads[consumerthreads];
         for (z=0; z<consumerthreads; z++) {
         remp->rop = z;
         d = *(remp->rep + z);
         d->da = z;
         pthread_create((Consumer_Threads+z), 0, Consumer, d);


         }
         for (z = 0; z<consumerthreads; z++) {
         pthread_join(Consumer_Threads[z], NULL);
         }
         shmdt(remp);

    }

    else{
       /*THIS WORKS*/
        printf("Entered Producer: %d\n",remp->rop);

        pthread_t Produc;
        pthread_create(&Produc, 0, Producer, remp); 
        pthread_join(Produc, NULL);


        printf("Hey guys: %d\n", remp->rop);
        shmdt(remp);
    }
```

My guess is that I didn't initialize the struct correctly, but I'm not all too clear what I'm doing wrong. I left out some of the other initializing code but I figured since I can't even access the int in the OverSharedData struct, it's more of a matter where I can't access the struct in the first place.

Comment: you need to use mmap to make shared data, not malloc

Comment: Do I need to use mmap to first declare the variable "remp" or will shmat take care of that? And I'm guessing I just replace all the mallocs in the initialize function with "mmap"?

Comment: right up front when you get the memory from the OS, you need to tell it you want it to be shared memory. be wary though, mmapping shared memory is nothing like malloc'ing. look at the function signature of mmap, its got like 6 arguments.

Comment: Or instead of mmap you could use shmget and shmat to allocate a block of memory big enough to hold all of the shared data. This might be easier since you're already using them for part of it. The important thing is don't expect malloc'ed memory to become shared just because you stored a pointer to it someplace that is shared.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley How would I allocate a block that's big enough to contain all of it? Just guess a size that's big enough to contain all the structs?

Comment: If you're going to do it that way, you don't guess... you run through your initialization loop adding up the sizes (and making adjustments for alignment). Then you shmget/shmat (or mmap) the total size. Then you run through the initialization loop again, carving out pieces from the big block with simple pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your shared data (the single `OverSharedData` object) contains pointers to non-shared data.  You need to allocate all the data that you want shared in the shared memory segment, rather than with malloc.  Something like:

```
static void *shared_available;
static size_t shared_left;
void init_shared(size_t size) {
    key_t key = ftok("garbage.txt", 71);
    int eyedee = shmget(key, size,
                        IPC_CREAT | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP);
    if (eyedee == -1) {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1); }
    shared_available = shmat(eyedee, 0, 0);
    if (shared_available == (void *) -1) {
        perror("shmat");
        exit(1); }
    shared_left = size;
}
void *alloc_shared(size_t size) {
    void *rv = shared_available;
    if (size > shared_left) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Ran out of shared memory!\n");
        exit(1); }
    shared_available = (char *)rv + size;
    shared_left -= size;
    return rv;
}

OverSharedData *initialize() {
    init_shared(sizeof(struct OverSharedData) +
                       sizeof(struct SharedData *) * consumerthreads +
                       sizeof(struct SharedData) * consumerthreads)
    OverSharedData *bill = alloc_shared(sizeof(OverSharedData));
    bill->rep = alloc_shared(sizeof(struct SharedData*)*consumerthreads);
    for (int on=0; on<consumerthreads; on++) {
        bill->rep[on] = alloc_shared(sizeof(struct SharedData));
        init(&bill->rep[on], on); }
}
```

The above will still have problems if the `init` routine tries to store pointers to non-shared memory into the `SharedData` struct (you don't show the definition of either, so we can't say).

If you want to be able to more flexibly allocate and manage shared memory across processes, you really need to use a general purpose shared memory allocator/manager, such as [this](https://github.com/ChrisDodd/shm_malloc)